# convert big varbinary into text field (MSSQLSERVER)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I try to fetch a big textcontent (<8000 chars) of a varbinary(max) field as follow:

```
CAST(varbinary_as_text AS VARCHAR(10000)) AS varbinary_as_text
```

I get the following error due the varchar is limited to 8000 chars:

```
java.sql.SQLException: The size (10000) given to the type 'varchar' exceeds the maximum allowed for any data type (8000).
```

How to fetch the text (> 8000 chars) content of a varbinary(max) field ?

Comment: It might work - CAST(varbinary_as_text AS TEXT) AS varbinary_as_text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast it as text

```
CAST(varbinary_as_text AS TEXT) AS varbinary_as_text
```

OR
Cast it as varchar(max)

```
CAST(varbinary_as_text AS varchar(max)) AS varbinary_as_text
```

Comment: @mcflysoft . . . Do not use `TEXT`.  It has been deprecated for ages:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15.

Comment: I realized, that it can't be casted to TEXT. Thanks for helping !